# Cannot establish RMI connection to remote machine

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rmi, distributed-computing

I can't seem to connect 2 machines using RMI. To make sure there wasn't something wrong with my code I copied the simple example from wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) and I edited the code to print out a simple int.

I tried giving all permissions and turning all the firewalls off and I still get this error:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host 55.229.xx.xxx; nested 
exception is:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I've been trying to do this for the past 3 days and I still can't seem to get past basic configuration problems.

Comment: Your RMI sever running in a linux based machine?

Comment: Yes. But I tried to swap, running the server on Windows and the client on Linux. I still couldn't make it work

Answer (score 5):

The Problem could be your RMI server is sending back its local address, instead of WAN address.

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", *host IP*);
```

also take a look at security policies regarding RMI:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/running.html

Comment: Still, connection timed out.

Comment: +1 for the `java.rmi.server.hostname` solution only. Security policies have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall settings on your aws instance
RMI is running on 1099 port by default as i remember.